# Laravel : foreach in the mail sender

Tags: php, database, laravel, email, cart

I want to add a foreach in my email to show the product sell in the mail. 
It's working fine without the foreach.

With the foreach, It's show's me the error :`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'e-shop.order_product' doesn't exist`

placed.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
# Order Received
@foreach ($order->products as $product)
Name: {{ $product->name }} <br>
Price: ${{ round($product->price / 100, 2)}} <br>
Quantity: {{ $product->pivot->quantity }} <br>
@endforeach

@endcomponent
```

OrderPlaced.php

```
use App\Order;

class OrderPlaced extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $order;

    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->to($this->order->billing_email, $this->order->billing_name)->subject('Commande reçue')->markdown('emails.orders.placed');
    }
}
```

Order.php

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'billing_email', 'billing_name', 'billing_address', 'billing_city',
        'billing_province', 'billing_postalcode', 'billing_phone', 'billing_name_on_card', 'billing_discount', 'billing_discount_code', 'billing_subtotal', 'billing_tax', 'billing_total', 'payment_gateway', 'error',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}
```

OrderProduct.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_products';

    protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity'];
}
```

I don't know what is the problem and why i can't add this foreach inside my mail

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show your Order model, please?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? As far as I read the error message, it is not connected to mailing or the concept of a cart after all, but a database problem

Comment: Sorry, i just edit my post with it

Comment: Double-check your `products` relationship. You're using a pivot table -- is the pivot table named `order_product`? If not, you're going to have to pass the table name through. `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'name_of_table', 'product_id_column', 'order_id_column')->withPivot(['quantity']);`

Comment: The name of my table is not order_product but order_products.

Comment: Laravel will default the table name to the snake case of the two classes, which is `Order` and `Product`. To override it, you have to pass the table name in.

Comment: how i can do that ?

Comment: I showed that in my previous comment

Comment: I add this line in the order model --> function product() ````return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_products', 'product_id', 'order_id')->withPivot(['quantity']);````  I have the same error but it's now show me Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Comment: It should now be a different error. What is the full error message?

Comment: ````SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'e-shop.order_product' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `order_product` (`order_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (27, 1, 1, 2020-05-26 14:17:14, 2020-05-26 14:17:14))````

Comment: Hmm, you should not be getting that error message when you pass in the table name. Also, that error is on an insert, not from the `placed.blade.php`.